# Vagrant synced folder using NFS wrong permissions

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

Trying to use the `NFS` plugin with a synced folder in Vagrant, and it is working, except that in the guest (VM) the permissions are wrong:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1  501 dialout    0 Jan 20 00:51 a
-rw-r--r-- 1  501 dialout    0 Jan 20 00:51 foo
```

I tried setting up the `uid` and `gid` according to the Vagrant documentation in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.nfs.map_uid = 1001
config.nfs.map_gid = 1001
```

Which I was hoping would use the correct user/group in the guest, but it is still using `501` and `dialout`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which specific plugin are you using? I see several NFS-related Vagrant plugins available. Also, you can set the user and group permissions on a synced folder in Vagrant without needing a plugin: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Comment: can you add something like `:mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]` in your sync_folder configuration ?

Comment: what is your OS host for Vagrant ?

Comment: Host is OS X. Using the default built in NFS support baked into Vagrant.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on a MacOS Catalina host and Ubuntu 18.04 guest (Vagrant 2.2.9, VirtualBox 6.1.12):

```rb
opts = {
  type: 'nfs',
  linux__nfs_options: ['no_root_squash'],
  map_uid: 0,
  map_gid: 0
}

config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/var/www/project', opts
```

You can then `chown` and `chmod` as usual:

```sh
$ sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/www/project
$ sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/project/logs
```

**ATTENTION**: `no_root_squash` is fine for development environments, but DON'T use it for production. It allows remote root users to change any file in the shared file system.

Another option might be to use the [vagrant-bindfs](https://github.com/gael-ian/vagrant-bindfs) plugin. But I didn't feel like installing and configuring an extra plugin for this.

Comment: For Ubuntu host and Ubuntu guest I get it works without `linux__nfs_options`: `opts = {type: 'nfs', map_uid: 0, map_gid: 0}`

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue. It started after I've upgraded my MacOS to mcOS Sierra version 10.12.1. The trick that worked for me was to set/force the owner and group to the 'vagrant' user in Vagrantfile like this:

```
    config.vm.synced_folder "/users/myuser/src/", "/home/vagrant/src/", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant"
```

I also had to remove the 'nfs: true' setting that was previously there in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: This is not a solution, it's simply turning off NFS instead of fixing the problem :-(